# How to make screen scrollable when using keyboard in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make my screen scrollable when the user tries to press on the text-field and the keyboard comes up. I tried using `SingleChildScrollView` as well as `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property but that doesn't seem to work. Here is my code.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:graffiti_app3/controller/controllerlistview.dart';

import 'package:graffiti_app3/view/screens/homepage/homepage.dart';

import '../../../model/modellistview.dart';
import '../homepage/dummyhomepage.dart';

class MyPostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final File? image;

  MyPostPage({required this.image, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyPostPage> createState() => _MyPostPageState();
}

class _MyPostPageState extends State<MyPostPage> {
  File? image;
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  // String description = "";

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void callAddCard() {
    MyDummyHomePageState? myWidgetState =
        context.findAncestorStateOfType<MyDummyHomePageState>();
    myWidgetState?.addCard();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    image = widget.image!;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                  '<  Add more details',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue.shade800,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Handle exit button press
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          )),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                        blurRadius: 7,
                        spreadRadius: 5,
                        offset: const Offset(0, 3)),
                  ],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                width: 360,
                height: 550,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage:
                                AssetImage('assets/images/userprofile.png'),
                            radius: 20,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              const Text(
                                "Maddy Perez",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Choose location",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.blue.shade800,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                      child: Image.file(
                        image!,
                        width: 330,
                        height: 330,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 340, // <-- TextField width
                      height: 120, // <-- TextField height
                      child: TextField(
                        autofocus: true,
                        controller: myController,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        maxLines: null,
                        expands: true,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            filled: true, hintText: 'Enter a message'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                        side:
                            BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.pink.shade800)),
                    child: Text(
                      "Save as draft",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.pink.shade800,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Graffiti graffiti = Graffiti(
                        author: 'Alice Smith',
                        location: 'Miami',
                        image: image!,
                        description: myController,
                      );
                      GraffitiController graffitiController =
                          GraffitiController();
                      graffitiController.addGraffiti(graffiti);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.pink.shade800,
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      "POST NOW",
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `SingleChildScrollView` instead of `Center`:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.fo(context).size.height,
    child: Column(
      ...
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for replying. I tried this approach but nothing is happening.